# Filter by model field, Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a model that creates an article and I want it to have a value for 'country' and 'category.' I want to be able to then filter by those values. So, if someone clicks on the country, it will return all articles for that country, and that can be further filtered by category.

the model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    """Represents a wiki article"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Publish?")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedArticlesManager()
    country = models.ChoiceField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

What I want to do is use this url:

```
url(r'^country/(?P<country\w+)' , 'wiki.views.country',
        name = 'wiki_country'),
```

where country comes from the the user clicking on a link, which then returns a page with the articles that correspond to articles with that country

This is a template snippet that currently lists all articles

```
{% if object_list %}

    <h2 class="articlePageTitle">All Articles</h2>
    <h3>Filter by country</h3>
    <h3>Filter by category</h3>

    <ul>
        {% for article in object_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url wiki_article_detail article.slug %}">{{ article.title }}</a>
        </li>
{% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I think I can add a filter to the template tag, but I'm not sure what to do in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Article.objects.filter(country=country_name)" will return all the Article objects with country = country_name.

Comment: Add your views.country , so it will be easy to understand the actual problem.

Comment: The views part is what I am trying to figure out. I will work on it, thannks for the above.